# Using contains after using filter in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to check if there are other files that doesn't contain the sub string "Sys" but does end with ".vm", but I am getting an error saying :

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching contains(::Array{String,1}, 
::SubString{String})
Closest candidates are:
contains(::Function, ::Any, ::Any) at reduce.jl:664
contains(::AbstractString, ::AbstractString) at strings/search.jl:378
```

This is the code:

```
    for f2 in filter(x -> endswith(x, ".vm"), readdir())

            if  (!contains(f2,"Sys"))
              #Do something with this file
            end
    end
```

I encountered the same problem after using readlines on the output of the filter:

```
    for f3 in filter(x -> !startswith(x, "Sys"), readdir())
                calledFileFunction = readlines(f3)
                fileLength=length(calledFileFunction)
                for i=1:fileLength
                    if  (contains(calledFileFunction,"ball"))
                           #Do something
                    end                  
                end
    end
```

Is there a way to cast f2 to regular substring and not "Array{String,1}" so I could use contains ?, otherwise how should I implement those functions ?

Comment: You need a minimum working example so that people can help you. Right now it is hard to help or even understand your intention.

Comment: This is very odd. Your first code snippet looks like it should work, and does in fact work on my computer. Are you sure this is actually the code that produces the error message? `"Sys"` is anyway not a `SubString`, so something is off with your example.

Comment: Yep, it works for me too. Either the example code here is wonky and doesn't demonstrate the issue, or something in your environment is redefining `contains` in a buggy incomplete way.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, `calledFileFunction` appears to be an array of strings. So `contains` needs to be applied to each element of the (to be renamed...) array...

`@show typeof(...)` is a useful thing to insert into your code if you're getting started.

Something like this might do:

```
for f3 in filter(x -> startswith(x, "test"), readdir())
   filecontents = readlines(f3)
   fileLength=length(filecontents)
   if any(map(f -> contains(f, "julia"), filecontents))
        println("$f3 contains \"julia\"")
   end                  
end
```